# JADE - Instances of agent Class

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade

I am building a multi-agent system where I have a type of agent X to alert other agent Y about something.
The thing is, I need to run different instances of the agent X but with different AID.

How can I do this without creating multiple classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create several agent of the same type by specifying different names for each instance...

```
java jade.Boot agent1:AgentX;agent2:AgentX;agent3:AgentY
```

Comment: I had to escape the semicolon `\;` between the agent specifiers on my linux terminal. Somehow the command terminated at the first semicolon without it and would start only the first agent.